# How can I exclude a character when capturing regex group in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, regex, jupyter-notebook

The current code is:

```
"...GO-Results-?T?o?p?-Price-TXT-Regular">(?P<cena>.*?) €</div>'
```

Now, this group `(?P<cena>.*?)` captures a price of some items. But the price is given as, for example, 5.400 €. So, this group captures 5.400 . I want it to capture 5400. I have been looking all over the internet on how to do that, but I can't find anything useful. Does anyone know how to do that?

I need that because I am using this data in Jupyter. But, it then changes 5.400 to 5.4. In my case, 5.400 means five thousand four hundred and not five point four, so this is unacceptable. If it is possible to change this in Jupyter (Pandas), I am also interested in this kind of a solution.

Comment: Change Jupyter's locale.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the group to arrive as a coherent unit, you can post-process it:

```
match.group('cena').replace('.', '')
```

More complicated version with multiple characters:

```
match.group('cena').translate(str.maketrans(dict.fromkeys('., ', '')))
```

Or you can just use regex again:

```
re.sub(r'\D', '', match.group('cena'))
```

Comment: I get an error that "match" is undefined. Where exactly do I need to put that piece of code?

Comment: @Matthew. The idea was not to blindly paste in my code. If you show how you're applying the regex in the question, maybe I can fix this. Right now, I assume that the result of your match is a `re.Match` object, called `match`.

Comment: I know and I also don't like that I'm doing this. But I have written the code for filtering and saving data about a year ago, now I am just trying to analyze it in Pandas. I don't know how, but i actually forgot almost everything about how this code even works. I am afraid to even slightly change it. Maybe if I post the entire code in the question ,you can help further?

Comment: Not the entire code, but a [mcve] or at least a relevant except

Comment: @Matthew. You can take a look at `ujemanje.groupdict()`. Save it to a variable (e.g., `gd`), and replace `gd['cena'] = gd['cena'].translate(...)` or whatever other method you want to use. This is pretty simple debugging. You can do it yourself, especially since I showed you how to edit the data.

Comment: @ Mad Physicist  Thanks a lot, I wouldn't be able to fix it without you!

Comment: @Matthew. Sure you would. It takes time and elbow grease, but I'm sure you could do it.